# Making sense of Yes/ No Type survey

Tags: statistical-significance, mean

I have a survey with 1 single question: 
Do you wish to join our club? Yes/ No

Apart from the usual % and count of yes/ no respondents, is there any other measure I can derive from this? For example, can I derive an average out of the survey and will it make sense?

Sorry if the question sounds a bit silly, but I have no statistical background and I'm really stumped.

Cheers

Comment: For this type of survey, the count of yes/no says it all. Everything else (such as the percentage) will just be derived from that

Comment: Given big enough dataset, there are statistical techniques that can cluster the respondents or questions in meaningful way. The survey might reveal interesting correlations. The CorEx method https://github.com/gregversteeg/CorEx does just that; it uses the notion of total correlation to reveal hidden structure in data, also in survey type data.

Comment: @xeon, how can one meaningfully cluster data if there is a single binary variable? There are exactly two "clusters", one for yes and one for no.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive an average by setting, for example, yes=1 and no=0. Your average will vary between 0 and 1 where values closer to 1 mean more yes responses. However, in this case, the average won't tell you any more than the percentage of yes and no responses. For example, if you had 70 yes responses and 30 no responses, your average would be 70/(70+30)=0.7. Your percentage of yes responses would be 70/(70+30)*100=70%.

If you have any other data (e.g. people's gender) you could start to look at more detailed statistics such as whether the rate of yes responses varies by gender. As it stands, all of your data is inherent in your counts. The percentage and average are essentially the same summary of these counts, presented in very slightly different ways.